# How to write query to find different between two row amount

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table like this i want to achieve out as mention below

```
EffectiveStartDate  PayElementCode           ElementAmount
04/01/2013           Basic                        14534
04/01/2013           HRA                           5814
04/01/2013           Education Allowance            200
04/01/2013           Special Allowance             2075
04/01/2013           Transportation Allowance       800
04/01/2013           Helper Allowance              3500
04/01/2013           Uniform Allowance              750
04/01/2013           LTA / LTC                     2083
04/01/2013           Medical Exp.                  1250

04/01/2014           Helper Allowance              3500
04/01/2014           Medical Exp.                  1250
04/01/2014           Tel & Mobile Exp.              600
04/01/2014           Petrol Running & Repairs      2500
04/01/2014           Attire Purchase               1667
04/01/2014           LTA / LTC                     2083
```

How to achieve below output writing query.

```
EffectiveStartDate  Amount      DiffAmount
2013-04-01          36335.00       0
2014-04-01          44085.00    7750
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare the value of two rows with SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814654/how-to-compare-the-value-of-two-rows-with-sql)

Comment: What is the DiffAmount column> What is it the difference between?

Comment: @Mike DiffAmount column which i want to achieve with Effectivestartdate and Amount

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my question - what are the 2 parts used to calculate DiffAmount?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved out put with

`;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.EffectiveStartDate),MONTH(p.EffectiveStartDate) as MM,YEAR(p.EffectiveStartDate) as YY, SUM(p.ElementAmount) as Salary,p.EffectiveStartDate as EffectiveDate,p.EmployeeID as EmployeeId
FROM tbl_EmployeePayElement p where EmployeeID=@EmployeeId and ISSalary=1  Group By EffectiveStartDate,EmployeeID
)
SELECT
CTE.EmployeeId, CTE.EffectiveDate, CTE.MM,CTE.YY, 
CTE.Salary,ISNULL(CTE.Salary-prev.Salary,0) as Diff
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN CTE prev ON prev.rownum = CTE.rownum - 1
LEFT JOIN CTE nex ON nex.rownum = CTE.rownum + 1`